# Show that there are at least $2$ elements in $U(n)$ such that $x^2=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am working on some exercises in Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*. I came upon the following:

> Show that there are at least $2$ elements in $U(n)$ such that $x^2=1$, for $n>2$

Remark: $U(n)$ is the set of natural numbers less than $n$ but are also relatively prime to $n$. (This forms a group under multiplication modulo $n$.)

Attempt:

$U(n)=\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

I note that $1$ is an element such that $x^2=1$. For the second element I suspect that it is $n-1$ but I am having difficulty proving it. Clearly $n$ and $n-1$ are relatively prime, so that's fine. If I can show that $(n-1)^2=1\mod n$, I'm done. Expanding I get that $n^2-2n+1$, but I'm not sure if this can lead me to conclude that it is equal to $1\mod n$. I don't know any number theory, so if there is a simple explanation involving rudimentary number theory or another way, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that two numbers are equivalent modulo $n$ if and only if $n$ divides their difference.

Comment: Another way of seeing this neatly is that is $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod $n$ then $a^2$ and $b^2$ are as well (this is just a special case of the well-definition of multiplication). But $n-1$ is congruent to $-1$ mod $n$. So $(n-1)^2$ is congruent to $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: @Mark Bennet: Thanks; I never realized that was the case.

Comment: You need to require $n > 2$. Also, please don't write $U(n) = \left\{1 , \ldots , n-1\right\}$; while I understand how it is meant, this can be too easily misunderstood for "the set of all integers from $1$ to $n-1$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed, they are $1$ and $n-1$ since $1^2=1$ and $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1=n(n-2)+1$.

In fact we can calculate the number of solutions for $k^2=1$ when $n=p^j$ with $p$ prime. Since this happens if and only if $k^2-1$ is a multiple of $p^j$ we need $(k+1)(k-1)$ to be a multiple of $p^k$. when $p=2$ the solutions are $k=1,k=2^j-1,k=2^{j-1}+1$ and $k=2^{j-1}-1$. so the number of solutions is as follows:

$2$ if $j=1$ and $4$ if $j>2$

when $p$ is not $2$ the only solutions are $1$ and $p^j-1$ since $k-1$ and $k+1$ are relatively prime.

From here the number of sultions to $k^2=1$ when $n=2^jp_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_m^{\alpha_m}$

is $4\cdot2^m$ if $j>2$ and $2\cdot2^m$ if $j=1,2$.

(you can prove this using the chinese remainder theorem).